# Firefox has permission to start wpa_supplicant when calling navigator.geolocation

Tags: firefox, security, permissions, systemd, wpa-supplicant

I've been dealing with some annoying attacks lately, and got super paranoid after discovering wpa_supplicant.service running as it definitely should not be on this particular machine.  After a little digging, I discovered this bit of code could start the wpa_supplicant.service:

```
// Check if geolocation is supported by the browser
  if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
    // Prompt user for permission to access their location
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    // Success callback function
    (position) => {
      // Get the user's latitude and longitude coordinates
      const lat = position.coords.latitude;
      const lng = position.coords.longitude;

      // Do something with the location data, e.g. display on a map
      console.log(`Latitude: ${lat}, longitude: ${lng}`);
    },
    // Error callback function
    (error) => {
      // Handle errors, e.g. user denied location sharing permissions
      console.error("Error getting user location:", error);
    }
  );
} else {
  // Geolocation is not supported by the browser
  console.error("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
}
```

Which got me thinking that if firefox has permissions to arbitrarily start a systemd service on my machine, what else can it do?  Does this strike anyone else as insanely insecure?  Are there any good resources on how to lock this down better?  Where can I see what firefox can and can't do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which got me thinking that if firefox has permissions to arbitrarily start a systemd service on my machine, what else can it do? Does this strike anyone else as insanely insecure?

Well, for one, this is not about it having permissions to start services, exactly.

If you run Firefox unconfined (i.e. not as a Flatpak/Snap), then it has all of the same permissions that *you* do; i.e. it is exactly as privileged as e.g. your terminal app or your file manager. Which means, on the one hand, it *doesn't* have any more permissions to start system services than you do – if you need to become root (or get approval via 'polkitd') to do something, then so does Firefox.

On the other hand, it means that Firefox has always had the permission to open any file with *your* permissions, as well as run any external program that would then work with your permissions – it could invoke `system("sudo reboot")` or it could delete your entire home directory without needing anything special. That's more or less 'normal'; that's how a desktop OS typically works.

(The risks of *web pages* gaining the rights that Firefox has are somewhat mitigated by Firefox having 'content' sub-processes that run with deliberately reduced permissions – although AFAIK its isolation mechanisms are still not nearly as extensive as what Chrome and Chromium-based browsers do, but it's a start.)

That being said, I rather doubt it explicitly starts wpa_supplicant or any other service. What it does is send a D-Bus message to a service – the Geoclue2 service, most likely – *as if* the service were running; and if the service is not running yet, then the D-Bus daemon starts it for you.

Geoclue2 then attempts to scan nearby Wi-Fi networks to determine rough location, and does so by sending another message to the wpa_supplicant service, which D-Bus also starts "on demand" in the same way. (Only the system bus starts system services; the user/session bus runs as you and starts services as you.) As a more direct example, whenever you run `hostnamectl`, D-Bus causes the 'hostnamed' service to be started even though you did not have permissions to `systemctl start` it.

So it's not correct that Firefox has unusual permissions to *arbitrarily* start systemd services; it can only start services that have opted-in to some form of "on demand start" by attempting to talk to them (in this case D-Bus activation, in a few other cases – socket activation).

Comment: Yeah, checking the owner of firefox should have been my first thought.  I did, and it's owned by root, which should probably not be the case.  Changed that to an unprivileged user.  I've been weary of digging into D bus, but it would seem I need to.  There have been several instances where my investigations led me to it and halting because I didn't want to open that whole can of worms.  I am aware of the built in dbus inspector.  In any case, thanks for clarifying.  I'll follow up on the systemd-dbus connection, in general.

Comment: The owner of the `firefox` binary has nothing to do with it, unless the program is +setuid. Practically **all** binaries installed through packages are owned by root, and it has no effect on the privileges they receive.

Comment: Wow, I've always sort of intuitively known the perms of a binary are set based on the calling user.  Which seems obvious in hindsight, all system binaries are owned by root, but I still can't use them as if I were root... Been using Linux for a while now and never explicitly put two and two together.  I always changed the ownership of binaries and made sure they were run as an unprivileged user, but never really thought about the nuts and bolts of it.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, based on the *calling* user, not on the *owning* user. The only exception is binaries that are explicitly marked setuid (u+s or g+s; such as /usr/bin/sudo), which then receive the owning-user privileges, but these are far and few between. (You can do a `find /usr -type f -perm /u+s,g+s -ls` to get a list of those.)